# 2 way communication over http between a .Net service and Windows Forms Client

Tags: wcf, http, windowsformshost

I am looking to accomplish 2 way communication over http between a .Net service (WCF SOAP or REST, both options are open) hosted on IIS 7 and Windows Forms Client running on Windows 7.

WebSockets are not supported with IIS 7 and all other Comet techniques allow only the web server to push data to client and not the other way around.

The client will be very chatty, and there are thousands of clients, so I want to avoid creating a new HTTP request for each message to the server, though that is the last option.

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Consider using SignalR. Chances are it will use Server Sent Events on an IIS 7 server. But the day you upgrade to II7.5/8 it will silently start using WebSockets instead.

Comment: Server Sent Events are available only with a Browser Client, while mine is a Windows Form.

Comment: There is a .net client library. Use that. Abstract away your Real Time Communication layer.